# Correct usage of Grand Central Dispatch with multiple UIActivityIndicatorViews

Tags: ios, uiactivityindicatorview, grand-central-dispatch

I am creating a thumbnail viewer consisting of UIButtons, and want to have a spinner in each button until the image gets populated from the cloud.  I've done this with single spinners before, but never en masse like this.  The spinners aren't coming up (maybe a non-main thread UI issue?)...am I at least headed in the right direction?  Thanks in advance.

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0);
dispatch_queue_t queue2 = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0);
dispatch_apply(numberOfThumbs, queue, ^(size_t i){
    Post *post = [arrayOfPosts objectAtIndex:i];
    UIActivityIndicatorView *newSpinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    UIButton *currentThumb = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] retain];
    [currentThumb setFrame:CGRectMake((105.5 * (i%3))+3.5, ((i/3)*105.5) + 3.5, 102, 102)];
    [newSpinner setFrame:CGRectMake(54 - spinner.frame.size.width/2, 54 - spinner.frame.size.height/2, spinner.frame.size.width, spinner.frame.size.height)];
    [currentThumb addSubview:newSpinner];
    [newSpinner startAnimating];
    [thumbnails addObject:currentThumb];
    dispatch_async(queue2, ^(void){
        [currentThumb setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:post.thumbUrl]]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [newSpinner stopAnimating];
        [newSpinner removeFromSuperview];
        [newSpinner release];
    });
    [currentThumb release];
});
dispatch_release(queue);
dispatch_release(queue2);
```

Thanks to Daniel and Brad's suggestion, below, the following dance seems to work:

```
    - (id)initWithArrayOfPosts:(NSArray*)posts
    {
        self = [super initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        if (self) {
            // Custom initialization
            arrayOfPosts = [posts retain];
            numberOfThumbs = [arrayOfPosts count];
            oldDequeueFactor = 0;
            oldYOffset = 0.0;
            thumbnails = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:15];
            mainScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
            [mainScrollView setFrame:self.view.frame];
            [mainScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, 109 * (ceilf((float)numberOfThumbs/3.0)))];
            [mainScrollView setDelegate:self];
            [mainScrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
            [self setView:mainScrollView];

            for (int i=0; i<numberOfThumbs; i++) {
                UIActivityIndicatorView *newSpinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
                UIButton *currentThumb = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] retain];
                [currentThumb setFrame:CGRectMake((105.5 * (i%3))+3.5, ((i/3)*105.5) + 3.5, 102, 102)];
                [newSpinner setFrame:CGRectMake(54 - newSpinner.frame.size.width/2, 54 - newSpinner.frame.size.height/2, newSpinner.frame.size.width, newSpinner.frame.size.height)];
                [currentThumb addSubview:newSpinner];
                [newSpinner startAnimating];
                [thumbnails addObject:currentThumb];
                [currentThumb release];
                [mainScrollView addSubview:[thumbnails objectAtIndex:i]];
                [self getImageDataAsynchronouslyForThumbnail:[thumbnails objectAtIndex:i] forIndex:i andRemoveSpinner:newSpinner];
            }
        }
        return self;
    }

    - (void)getImageDataAsynchronouslyForThumbnail:(UIButton*)thumb forIndex:(int)index andRemoveSpinner:(UIActivityIndicatorView *)spinner
{
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0);

    dispatch_async(queue, ^(void){
        Post *post = [arrayOfPosts objectAtIndex:index];
        UIImage *thisImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:post.thumbUrl]]];
        NSArray *args = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:thisImage, thumb, spinner, nil];
        if ([args count] == 3) { //use this array to verify I have all info I need
            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
                [self setImage:[args objectAtIndex:0] ForThumbnail:[args objectAtIndex:1] andStopAnimatingSpinner:[args objectAtIndex:2]];
            });
        } else {
            [self getImageDataAsynchronouslyForThumbnail:thumb forIndex:index andRemoveSpinner:spinner];
            return;
        }
    });

    dispatch_release(queue);

}

- (void)setImage:(UIImage*)image ForThumbnail:(UIButton *)thumb andStopAnimatingSpinner:(UIActivityIndicatorView *)spinner
{
    [thumb setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [spinner stopAnimating];
    [spinner removeFromSuperview];
    [spinner release];
}
```

Comment: If it helps any, the code seems to work for *some* thumbnails on the device, never on the simulator.

Comment: In your revised code, I believe that you could replace the `-performSelectorInBackground:` with `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{})` to keep everything within GCD and avoid having to create the temporary NSArray for arguments.

Comment: Ooh, that should have been performSelectorInMainThread:withObject, in any case.  Let me revise, and try some GCD only options.  Thanks.

Comment: Updated with Brad's suggestion to use only GCD for threading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes i believe your issue is that you are executing code from a background thread, UIKit isnt thread safe, so you should probably only get the image data in the background then use performSelectorOnMainTHread in order to set the image and stop animating, something like

```
-(void)setDataStopAnimating:(NSArray*)args
{
   //get your arguments from the array and then run
 [thumb setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [newSpinner stopAnimating];
                [newSpinner removeFromSuperview];
                [newSpinner release];
}

//then in your queue code
      dispatch_async(queue2, ^(void){
               NSArray *args; //fill the array with the arguments
                [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setDataAndStopAnimating:) withObject:args] 
            });
```

Comment: Ooh, OK.  I'll give it a whirl.  I'd never mixed performSelector and GCD, thanks.

Comment: @diatrevolo i havent tried it either, so it might not work, if it doesnt then you can just perform selectorOnBackground to get data, do let us know if it works tho...

Comment: UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData] is thread-safe, I think. - [Crash with UIImage Category Image Release???](https://devforums.apple.com/message/360659#360659)

Comment: it also caches it which might not be the desired behavior

Comment: OK just tested this and it DOES seem to work.  I'll report back if I find any caveats, but so far, so good.  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Adding the modified code to my original question for reference.

Comment: Instead of `-performSelectorOnMainThread:`, you could use the GCD way of `dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{})` (or dispatch_async if you don't want to block until the main thread action is complete).  This avoids the need for passing in an arguments array.